# What is the meaning of device label last part (ex - 413c:c00f) in deviceInfo from enumerateDevices?

Tags: javascript, webrtc, mediainfo, enumerate-devices

I am querying for devices using enumerateDevices and listing the labels of all microphone devices. The labels are like -
Communications - Headset Microphone (Jabra Link 370) (0b0e:245e)
Echo Cancelling Speakerphone (8- C3422WE) (413c:c00f)
Microphone Array (Realtek(R) Audio)

What is the meaning of this id part at the end of some device labels like (0b0e:245e) and (413c:c00f)? Is it persistent?

I would like to store the last used device label but i am not sure if this part of the label also stays consistent.

Answer (score 3):

This is a numeric representation of the vendor and device ID. For gthe Jabra link see [this database](https://devicehunt.com/view/type/usb/vendor/0B0E/device/245E) which shows the combination of vendor id 0B0E for GN Netcom (possibly the actual manifacturer) and 245E for the Jabra Link 370.

For the purpose of storing the last used device the label is pretty useless however. What you need to store is the [deviceId returned by enumerateDevices](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/enumerateDevices) since that can be used to ask the browser for that particular device in getUserMedia.
Note that this device id is only persistent within the lifetime of cookies, i.e. if the user clears cookies the device id will change. This typically isn't a problem as your identification of the user is gone too.

Comment: Note that in Chrome, deviceId does NOT change when the user clears cookies.

Comment: I'll note that the deviceId is not persistent if user blocks cookies though.